# Multi Line Text Area using htmlunit

Tags: java, javascript, html, htmlunit

**Requirement:** I have a multi line textarea in the webpage with some default value , i need to change that values and submit the form. The text area defnition is as below.

```
<textarea id="editorarea" name="_editedtext"
         class="editor"
       onkeyup="getSuggestions(this.id)"
       onclick="setCursorPos(this.id)"
      onchange="setCursorPos(this.id)"
          rows="20" cols="80">! Lorem ipsum" text is derived
from sections 1.10.32–3 of Cicero's De
finibus bonorum et malorum (On the Ends of Goods
```

**Problem:** When I set the text for the textarea from a string it becomes like below :

```
<textarea id="editorarea" name="_editedtext"
         class="editor"
       onkeyup="getSuggestions(this.id)"
       onclick="setCursorPos(this.id)"
      onchange="setCursorPos(this.id)"
          rows="20" cols="80">Lorem ipsum" text is derived&lt;br&gt;from sections 1.10.32–3 of Cicero's De &lt;br&gt;| LPAR Name If Remote:| N/A1&lt;br&gt;\\ &lt;br&gt;! Endpoints&lt;br&gt;finibus bonorum et malorum (On the Ends of Goods'&lt;br&gt;
```

so the the content becomes a single line, the line break is not getting recogonised, i tried "\n" , "
" both didn't work.

I am having my input in a arraylist and convert them to a single string as below:

```
public static void createString(){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(String s : finalModifiedList){
    sb.append(s);
sb.append("<br>");   
    }
    finalString =sb.toString();
```

and setting the textarea content as below

```
HtmlTextArea  erfTextarea = textAreaForm.getTextAreaByName("_editedtext");
erfTextarea.setText(content);
```

**TextArea Charset is : UTF-8**

Please let me know how to enter the multi-line text using htmlunit

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

replace `sb.append("<br>");`   with `sb.append("\n");`   in createString()